# Replace text in file to line end, using wildcard

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to replace a string in a file. Sample text file `File.txt`:

```
<add key="apple" value="C:\test\web.config"/>
<add key="banana" value="C:\test\web2.config"/>
<add key="orange" value="C:\test\web3.config"/>
```

This is the code I have so far, using a wildcard to match:

```
$content = Get-Content -Path C:\File.txt
$content -replace "<add key=`"apple*", '<add key="mango" value="C:\test\web.config"/>'
```

Output:

```
<add key="mango" value="C:\test\web.config"/>" value="C:\test\web.config"/>
```

Desired output:

```
<add key="mango" value="C:\test\web.config"/>
```

The wildcard character `*` is not matching to the end of the line.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a regex, maybe you need a `apple.*`  instead of `apple*` ?

I would say that by using `apple*` you are telling the regex to be "appl" and as many "e" as needed after that

Comment: Tested in the meanwhile -> works fine -> `    gc .\relplace.txt | foreach { $_ -replace "<add key=`"apple.*", '<add key="mango" value="C:\test\web.config"/>'}`